# CheckBox n Radio styling in SLDS

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-design-system

Is anyone know applying SLDS styling for Dynamic Radio & Checkboxes(options). I have tried the below code,but no success:

https://vishnuvaishnav.wordpress.com/tag/convert-visualforce-radio-buttons-in-lightning-design-system/

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS from LDS system.

[Lightning Design System](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/)

**Sample code:**

```
<fieldset class="slds-form-element">
  <legend class="slds-form-element__label slds-form-element__label--top">Options</legend>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <label class="slds-radio" for="lead">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="lead" />
      <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
      <span class="slds-form-element__label">Lead Generation</span>
    </label>
    <label class="slds-radio" for="education">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="education" />
      <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
      <span class="slds-form-element__label">Education Leads</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Tushar, can we create this dynamically. There could be N-number of options might available

Comment: yes put the part in Repeat and change label ad value. '<label class="slds-radio" for="education">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="education" />
      <span class="slds-radio--faux"></span>
      <span class="slds-form-element__label">Education Leads</span>
    </label>'